# Get results with 2 relationships Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models, let's say Product, Unit and Area.

There's a relationship between Product and Unit. A Unit may have a lot of Product.

There's another relationship between Product and Area. A Area may also have a lot of Product.

> The point here is: given an Area, get all of its Product **with** the
>   respective Unit.

To get all of Product given an Area is easy: `$area->products()`, but I would like to do `$area->products->with('unit')`.

Is there a way to do it? Or I will have to do a `foreach` through the products array and querying each Unit for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use nested relationships which are defined using dot notation.

```
$areas = Area::with('products.unit')->get();
```

That will eager load products and product->units with Area.

Then you can loop through them using nested loops...

```
foreach($areas as $area) {
    foreach($area->products as $product) {

        // If units are returning many
        foreach($product->unit as $unit) {

        }

        // Or if there is only one unit per product
        $unit = $product->unit;
    }
}
```

### Edit: Adding a where clause

If you need to add a `where` to the products, you need to separate the dot notation so you are querying for `products` and `products.unit`.

```
$area = Area::with(['products' => function($q) {
    $q->where('product_field', '=', 'something');
},'products.unit'])->find($area_id);
```

You should also check out the documentation which explains this more clearly than I probably can.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: This is a good way to do it! But I'm gonna do it to only one area! That's why I have the variable `$area`

Comment: Then instead of `...->get()`, you'd do `...->find($area_id)` and you'd just remove the very outer `foreach` loop.

Comment: It is working! But I would like to place a `where` condition related with the products model, and I just can't do it.

Comment: I've modified the answer, hopefully it helps